# picker view shows numbers in pickerview but not showing properly on label?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, uipickerview

i have added a pickerview from interface builder.i am using this method to show data like this....

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
if (pickerView == SpotPickerView) // don't show selection for the custom picker
{
  // report the selection to the UI label
 label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d - %@ - %d",[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0],
   [RowArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]],
   [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:2]];
}
}


- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
 NSString *returnStr = @"";
 if (pickerView == SpotPickerView)
 {
  if (component == 0)
  {
    returnStr = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:row+1] stringValue];
  }
  else if(component==1)
  {
    returnStr = [RowArray objectAtIndex:row];
  }
else
 {
   returnStr =[[NSNumber numberWithInt:row+1] stringValue];
  }
}

  return returnStr;
}

- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView widthForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
  CGFloat componentWidth = 0.0;

  if (component == 0)
  componentWidth = 90.0;
  else if (component == 1)
  componentWidth = 100.0; 
  else 
  componentWidth = 90.0; 

  return componentWidth;
}

- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component
 {
   return 40.0;
 }

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   int count;
   if (component == 0)
   count = 15;
  else if (component == 1)
   count=[RowArray count]; 
 else 
  count = 100;

 return count;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
   return 3;
}
```

here is the RowArray

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
RowArray = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
  @"A", @"B", @"C",
  @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G",@"H",@"I",@"J",@"K",@"L",@"M",@"N",@"O",@"P",@"Q",@"R",@"S",@"T",
  @"U",@"V",@"W",@"X",@"Y",@"Z",
  nil] retain];
}
```

but selecting the first row shows this.

[image]

i need to store the values in database so i need the 1 instead of zero.

also how do i reset my picker view.means when i click on a button it automatically comes to the 0th index in each column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d - %@ - %d",[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0],
    [RowArray objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]],
    [pickerView selectedRowInComponent:2]];
```

This code is retrieving the row number from the selected row in a component. Arrays are zero indexed and the pickerview (probably) uses array's to manage the rows. So, the first row will be 0, the second 1, the third 2 and so on. This is easily solved by doing:

`[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0] + 1`

You can select certain rows programmatically by using `selectRow:inComponent:animated` If you want the select the 0th index in each column just do: `[pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES]` for every component.